# Why it is called 91 days if there were only 12?

Tags: 91-days

So, basically the question in the title. I thought it had something to do with how long it took for Angelo to complete his revenge but I'm not too sure.

Comment: If you count the number of days per week and include epi 7.5, 13 episodes x 7 days in a week = 91 days.

Comment: In episode 10, Corteo comments that it's been 3 months since they returned to Lawless. 91 might well be the number of days between Avilio returning to Lawless in episode 1, and leaving again in episode 12.

Answer (score 6):

The 90 days signify the days left until the opening of the Opera House, which was mentioned in the wedding episode 2 by Frate, who tells them that Don Gallasia decided to attend the opening show. The 91 days refers to the time in which his revenge takes place since arriving.